# AFNetworking progress

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

I am trying to use `setDownloadProgressBlock` of AFHTTPRequestOperation class. The call back gives me 3 parameters:

```
( NSInteger bytesRead , NSInteger totalBytesRead , NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToRead )
```

In order for me to get the progress, I need the totalBytesExpectedToRead value, but it's giving me a -1. I checked the headers of the HTTP response and the content length is there...

```
{
    "Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 36902;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain";
    Date = "Sat, 03 Mar 2012 23:53:11 GMT";
    Expires = "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=95";
    "Last-Modified" = "Sat, 03 Mar 2012 23:53:11 GMT";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.3.6-13ubuntu3.3";
}
```

Is this a problem with the AFNetworking framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the following response, it's a limitation of NSURLConnection related to the content being in gzip format: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7426735/250164

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the input. Is there a way this gzip can be turned off?

Comment: I wouldn't advise it, but that's something you'd have to disable on the server. I would personally rather have my responses load faster than have a progress indicator to show me long it takes to load (that is, unless the data in question doesn't lend itself to gzip compression in the first place, like image data, which is already compressed).

Comment: You should be able to disable it on the client end by indicating via the request headers that you don't accept gzip data.

Comment: adding the header "Accept-Encoding:" with no arguments should solve the problem.

Comment: Doing a HEAD request before the GET would give you the information you need.