# totalBytesExpectedToRead in setDownloadProgressBlock remains -1 until download is done

Tags: xcode, download, afnetworking

I have been googling to no avail, and hope for your help on this.

I tried to download an image using AFHTTPRequestOperation streaming (by setting outputstream).
It downloads the file, no problem.
But the progress bar wont display correct, because totalBytesExpectedToRead always returns -1, and only returns the correct value when download is complete.

Is this the nature of streaming?
Or did I do something wrong?

My code below.

Thanks in advance!

(void)invokeAsynchronousSTREAMING:(NSString*)path locationToSave:(NSString*)locationToSave parameters:(NSDictionary*)paramDict callId:(NSString*)callId {

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFServerAPIClient sharedClient] requestWithMethod:@"GET" 
                                                                              path:path 
                                                                        parameters:paramDict];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

if(locationToSave!=nil) {
    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:locationToSave append:NO];
}

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)  {

   //DO SOMETHING

} 
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
 ];

[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {

    NSLog(@"invokeAsyncronousSTREAMING - Received %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead);

    //DO SOMETHING
}];

[operation start];
```

}//end invokeAsyncStreaming

Answer (score 9):

Download progress may return `-1` if the server does not set the `Content-Length` HTTP header in the response.

In this case, it is recommended that you use an indeterminate progress indicator instead.

Answer (score 5):

Also, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550971/afnetworking-progress), if gzip compression is used during the transfer, `totalBytesExpectedToRead` will still return `-1` even if the header does contain a `Content-Length` (both cases being quite frequent). This is because the contents can only be uncompressed at the end of the transfer, hence its size won't be known before the transfer completes.