# Swift - Alamofire totalBytesExpectedToRead returns -1 even Content-length is set

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

totalBytesExpectedToRead returns -1 even Content-length has a value

I found the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37560461/alamofire-progress-returns-1-even-though-content-length-is-set) here on stackoverflow but was not answered

Here's my code:

```
Alamofire.download(.POST, urlString, headers: headers, destination: destination)   
       .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
            print("totalBytesRead: \(totalBytesRead)")
            print("totalBytesExpectedToRead: \(totalBytesExpectedToRead)\n\n")
        }
        .response { request, response, data, error in
        }
```

Server response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers →Link
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →163
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:12:56 GMT
```

Result:

```
totalBytesRead: 1211
totalBytesExpectedToRead: -1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely something wrong with what the server sends you: the announced `Content-Length` (163 bytes) is smaller that what you actually receive (1211 bytes).

It seems that there is only one call to the progress block, and I would say that Alamofire sets `totalBytesExpectedToRead` to -1 as a response to the incoherence between what is announced by the server and what is received.

Comment: I will check the server. Thanks @François for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Pass Accept-Encoding key in header.

It worked for me.

```
let headers = ["Accept-Encoding" : ""]

Alamofire.download(.POST, urlString, headers: headers, destination: destination)   
       .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
            print("totalBytesRead: \(totalBytesRead)")
            print("totalBytesExpectedToRead: \(totalBytesExpectedToRead)\n\n")
        }
        .response { request, response, data, error in
        }
```

[Check accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136020/response-expectedcontentlength-return-1)