# response.expectedContentLength allway return -1

Tags: nsurlconnection, httpresponse, nsurlrequest, nshttpurlresponse

i have a connection use NSURLConnection, i want to draw a progress for this connection but when i try to print current received data and total data length, something went wrong ,response.expectedContentLength allway return -1, why and what happen with my connection, how can i fix it

```
 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
    {
        receivedDataBytes += [data length];
        NSLog(@"data: %f",receivedDataBytes);
        [responseData appendData:data];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
    {
        self.HTTPStatusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
        totalFileSize = response.expectedContentLength;
        NSLog(@"total: %lf",totalFileSize);
    }
```

output:

```
total: -1.000000
data: 1256.000000
total: -1.000000
data: 1034.000000
total: -1.000000
data: 1127.000000
```

Comment: I have the same problem but it just happens with small files, with big files from the same server everything is OK.

Comment: my image file ís about 2-4MB, i think it is enoungh big

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417610/why-response-expectedcontentlength-always-return-1