# NSURLConnection Receiving Data in Percentage

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I have a simple NSURLConnection I want to get the parsing data progress percentage. That is how much percentage loaded. Is it possible to calculate.
I have tried this,

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    urlData = [NSMutableData data];
    [urlData setLength:0];
  expectedBytes = [response expectedContentLength];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
float progressive = (float)[urlData length] / (float)expectedBytes;
}
```

here, **`expectedBytes` getting -1.** The json link is working getting jsonResult.
Let me know how to Calculate the loading progress.

Comment: It has to be sent from server to determine the expected length. Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417610/why-response-expectedcontentlength-always-return-1) would help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code. This will work for you,Simple and easy.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response{
      urlData = [NSMutableData data];
      [urlData setLength:0];
      double expectedBytes = [[[response allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Content-Length"] doubleValue];
    }

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
      float progressive = (float)[urlData length] / (float)expectedBytes;
}
```

Comment: You should change   "-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response" to "-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response " to make this work

Comment: Error : no visible @interface of NSURLConnection.

Comment: Change  NSURLConnection to NSUHTTPRLConnection in didRecieveResponse method